# Como é que o Laravel "guarda" as rotas?

Tags: php, laravel, framework

No `Laravel`, tanto no 4 como no 5, podemos utilizar uma classe chamada `Route` para poder criar determinadas rotas.

A minha curiosidade é: como é que o `Laravel` (ou outros frameworks) fazem para "saber" que determinada rota corresponde à uma url?

Por acaso tudo isso é salvo em algum `array` e depois, quando a requisição é feita, a rota é chamada?

Onde fica a lista dessas rotas?

Isso é importante saber, principalmente para quem quer aprender a fazer uma framework.

Comment: Até onde eu sei é feito um "mapeamento" entre a rota, e controller, função ou que será executado, quando está rota for acessada. Acredito que seja feito algum tipo de comparação (if aninhado) até encontrar a definição que bate com a url requerida.

Comment: Pelo nível de código fonte do Laravel duvido realmente que seja "ifs aninhados". Inclusive o Laravel 5 tem como fazer cache de rotas, não faz sentido ser "um monte de ifs"

Comment: Negativo? O que há de errado com a pergunta?

Comment: Tá, foi um palpite apenas .... Mas não importa bem como ele faz, por que no fundo, em qualquer linguagem de programação, a tarefa de tomar um caminho, ou outro, é sempre feito por meio de condicionais, seja ela no próprio script, ou em baixo nível, talvez em uma operação requisitada pelo interpretador ao SO, executada diretamente no processador ... hehe ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não entendi bem a pergunta, mas vou supor que usem `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` ou `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, no .htaccess do Laravel/Symfony não deve usar PATH_INFO porque ele esta assim:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

O path_info só é gerado no php se fizer algo semelhante a isto:

```
RewriteRule (*.?) index.php/$1 [L]
```

No caso PATH_INFO não funciona muito bem em alguns servidores diferentes do Apache, as vezes o resultado é diferente, mas o `REQUEST_URI` funciona de maneira idêntica no Apache, Ngnix, Lighttpd e IISExpress (não pude testar no IIS padrão mas acredito ser a mesma coisa).

A estrutura PHP deve ser algo como (essa é a estrutura que usei em um framework pessoal, no entanto esta simplificada, sem verificação de POST, GET, PUT, etc):

```
class Route
{
    private static $currentPath;
    private static $routes = array();

    public function path()
    {
        if (self::$currentPath) {
            return $currentPath;
        }

        //Pega o nome do script atual
        $sname  = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

        //Remove a query string da url
        $reqUri = empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ? null : preg_replace('#\?(.*)$#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

        //Subtrai o nome do script (se necessário)
        $pathInfo = substr(urldecode($reqUri), strlen(substr($sname, 0, -9)));
        $pathInfo = '/' . ($pathInfo === false ? '' : $pathInfo);

        return self::$currentPath = $pathInfo;
    }

    public function add($path, $controller)
    {
        self::$routes[$path] = $controller;
    }

    public function exec()
    {
         if (empty(self::$routes[$path])) {
              return false;
         }

         return self::$routes[$path];
    }
}
```

Existem muitas maneiras de "guardar" tais rotas, no caso da minha classe eu guardo em um `array` na mesma classe:

```
private static $routes = array();
```

Mas pode-se até guardar em lugares separados, vai depender do objetivo de uso final.

O uso seria algo como:

```
require 'route.php';

Route::add('/', 'ClasseController@indexaction');
Route::add('/blog', 'ClasseController@blogaction');
Route::add('/admin', 'AdminClasse@action');

echo 'Path: ', Route::path(), '<br>', PHP_EOL; //Retorna o PATH equivalente ao PATH_INFO
echo 'Controller: ', Route::exec(), '<br>', PHP_EOL; //Retorna o controler
```

Não posso afirmar que funciona exatamente desta maneira no Laravel/Symfony, mas esta explicação é pra entender como usar o `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` ou `PATH_INFO`.

### Laravel e o cache de Rotas

No Laravel existe uma estrutura de cache para as rotas (o qual você me citou) que após o comando (não funciona com funções anonimas):

```
php artisan route:cache
```

É gerado um arquivo em `projeto/bootstrap/cache/routes.php`, ele contem uma variavel php "serializada" (e codificada em base64) e usa o método `setRoutes` pra definir todas rotas que estão em cache pro "Collection", um exemplo de cache:

```
app('router')->setRoutes(
    unserialize(base64_decode('Código base64'))
);
```

Isto pode ser razoavelmente vantajoso para os servidores de produção.

Comment: Sim, o `Laravel` usa o `REQUEST_URI`. Na verdade, não é bem o `Laravel`, é o Symfony, que é usado pelo `Laravel`. O exemplo retrata sim o que acontece no `Laravel`, mas claro de maneira mais simplificada, visto que o `Laravel` usa 3 classes só pra fazer o roteamento :d

Answer (score 0):

Bem, vamos explicar por partes:

O Laravel, quando utilizamos a chamada da classe  `Route`, na verdade você está chamando um facade da classe `Illuminate\Routing\Router`.

Um `Router` serve para facilitar a criação de rotas (`Illuminate\Routing\Route`), que por sua vez será criado dentro de uma coleção de rotas pré-definidas (`Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection`).

Ao você invocar o `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex')` por exemplo, você está na verdade fazendo o seguinte:

```
 app('route')->get('/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
```

Que é a mesma coisa que :

```
app('route')->addRoute(['GET', 'HEAD'], '/', 'HomeController@getIndex');
```

Então temos que entender que:

1 - `Route` é um facade (fachada) para classe `Router`.

2 - `Router` é uma classe responsável pela criação de rotas dentro de uma coleção.

3 - `RouteCollection` é a lista de rotas. Cada vez que é chamado `Route::get` ou `Route::post`, essa rota é inserida dentro dessa classe.

4 - `Route` (não o facade, mas `Illuminate\Routing\Route`) é a rota propriamente dita. É a classe que representa uma entidade que é uma rota.

Internamente, o `Laravel` tem um método em `RouteCollection` que pega a primeira rota que bate com a expressão regular da `URI` da rota.

Quando nenhuma é encontrada, retorna uma exceção (que é o erro 404).

Veja o método `RouteCollection::match`, que faz esse serviço.

```
/**
 * Find the first route matching a given request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 *
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException
 */
public function match(Request $request)
{
    $routes = $this->get($request->getMethod());

    // First, we will see if we can find a matching route for this current request
    // method. If we can, great, we can just return it so that it can be called
    // by the consumer. Otherwise we will check for routes with another verb.
    $route = $this->check($routes, $request);

    if ( ! is_null($route))
    {
        return $route->bind($request);
    }

    // If no route was found, we will check if a matching is route is specified on
    // another HTTP verb. If it is we will need to throw a MethodNotAllowed and
    // inform the user agent of which HTTP verb it should use for this route.
    $others = $this->checkForAlternateVerbs($request);

    if (count($others) > 0)
    {
        return $this->getOtherMethodsRoute($request, $others);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

Então, podemos concluir, conforme foi perguntado, que as rotas são salvas numa coleção, que é responsável por retornar uma rota registrada de acordo com o conteúdo da requisição (o método http e a uri).

Comment: mas aí é um pouco diferente do que perguntou... esse é a parte onde as rotas vão sendo armazenadas quando são encontradas..O que entendi da pergunta é como que o laravel traduzia as rotas..

Comment: "Encontradas" não, quando são "declaradas". São "encontradas" (ou não) de acordo com a uri passada.

Comment: não entendi.. rsr encontrada ou declarada dá no mesmo pois a lógica do  padrão psr4 é "encontrar (o arquivo)" e carregar se estiver "declarada (a classe)"

Comment: Esquece então, deixa pra lá. Vamos ver se outros usuários também estão com dúvida sobre o que eu perguntei.

Comment: Estou sentindo um tom de represálias nesses negativos. Ainda dá pra perceber que alguns usuários na comunidade precisam amadurecer

Answer (score -1):

O Laravel usa o autoloader para identificar rotas. Você pode optar também por rotas pré definidas. 
Para os casos onde não há pre definição de rotas e o Laravel identifica-as automaticamente, muito provavelmente está aplicando o padrão [PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), o qual pode ser definido no composer

```
 "autoload": {
         "psr-4": {
             "App\\": "app/",
              "Mylib\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

<sub>exemplo ilustrativo</sub>

https://laracasts.com/lessons/psr-4-autoloading

Sempre que uma rota é invocada e encontrada, é armazenada em cache.

<sub>Não estou dizendo que o Laravel utiliza somente o PSR4. Isso é opcional nas configurações.</sub>

Esse cache das rotas é algo que pode ser bom ou ruim. Pois sempre carregará um arquivo contendo todas as rotas a cada requisição ou a cada vez que incoca, por exemplo. Está carregando ali uns kb que podem ser mais pesados do que verificar a rota em tempo de execução. Num projeto pequeno de 10, 20 rotas, pode ser vantagem, mas acima de 100, acredito que não.

Para otimizar, existe o [route group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups) onde podem ser divididos os arquivos de rotas, deixando-os em tamanhos menores. Por isso, quem usa muitas rotas deve usar esse recurso.

Comment: Para entender melhor porque você foi negativado, consulte o manual: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#basic-routing :)

Comment: O autoload é parte essencial do routing. É isso alguns aqui não entendem e por isso negativaram.

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem relação alguma com autoloading, não por acaso nenhuma das outras respostas abordam isso. Pegue o código de routing do Laravel, jogue tudo num arquivo só, adicione rotas fictícias com closures e você ainda poderá responder a pergunta. Não vou nem entrar no mérito do caching porque sua argumentação também está completamente equivocada.